# How to separate header body and footer

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to separate a header, body and footer, so when you open the page you can see the header and body and scroll for footer. I tried with margins but didn't get the results I wanted.
This is the CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(imagine2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    height: 58px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
    float: right;
}

.navbar li{
    display: inline;
}

.navbar li a {
    color: blanchedalmond;
    padding: 25px 50px;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
    color: chartreuse;
    background-color: cornsilk;
}
```

Comment: make this a snippet and add your html

Comment: You need to include your HTML in the question too.

Comment: @sinanspd that's `<head>` and `<body>`, not `<header>`.

Comment: @sinanspd that is incorrect. The <head> tag is used to the sites "meta information". A <header> tag is exactly what should be used as it semantically represents the content it contains as compared to a generic <div> tag. Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood. Your actual issue is keeping footer at the bottom. Here is a demonstration of how to keep footer at the bottom.

I recommend using CSS grids for all HTML templates. Otherwise it can be difficult to keep footer at the bottom for all screen sizes.
That being said, try using flexbox.

Insert all of your html in `main` and flexbox will push footer to the bottom of the page.

```css
/* The magic: */
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}

/* Stlyes to make the demo easier to see: */
body { margin: 0; }
header { background-color: #FD2D; }
main { background-color: #DFDD; }
footer { 
    background-color: #049e8c;
    height: 50pt;
    text-align: right;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body class="Site">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main class="Site-content">Content</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

If you want to try **CSS Grids**, you need to do something like this.
All HTML content goes into the `Site-content` section. Hope this helped :)

```css
/* Stlyes to make the demo easier to see: */
html{
      height: 100%;
    }
    
 body { 
  margin: 0; 
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-areas:
        "header_section"
        "Site-content_section"
        "footer_section";
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100% 50px; /* 100px for header, 100% for content section, 50px for footer */
}
.header { 
grid-area: header_section;
background-color: #FDD; 
}
.Site-content { 
grid-area: Site-content_section;
background-color: #DFD; 
}
.footer {
  grid-area: footer_section;
  background-color: #049e8c;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class= "header">Header</div>
  <div class="Site-content">Content</div>
  <div class= "footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

Comment: the `<footer>` and `<header>` element exists for a reason... bad semantics

Answer (score 0):

You can use a top margin of auto on the footer, but you have to set the body to flex. See the CSS code labeled /* Sticky footer */

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/1000);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    height: 58px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
    float: right;
}

.navbar li{
    display: inline;
}

.navbar li a {
    color: blanchedalmond;
    padding: 25px 50px;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
    color: chartreuse;
    background-color: cornsilk;
}

footer{
   background-color: yellowgreen;
   color: blanchedalmond;
   padding: 20px 20px;
}


/* sticky footer */
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
body{
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column;
}
footer{
   margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
   </ul>
</header>

<footer>This is the footer</footer>
```

Comment: this place the footer at the bottom of the page, but i don't have to scroll to see the footer. i want to scroll down to see the footer

Comment: @GabrielDaniel set the `html, body` height to greater than 100%.